Upgrading ruby version from 3.0.0 to 3.1.0 is throwing uninitialised constant Time::RFC2822_DAY_NAME error
Current Rails app has ruby 3.0.0 and trying to upgrade to ruby 3.1.0.
It's breaking with

uninitialised constant Time::RFC2822_DAY_NAM

error where it was previously working properly.
That line is calculating time with gem business_time along with Time.zone.now
And, there isn't any constant with name - Time::RFC2822_DAY_NAME.
Tried to search it but still looking for working solution.

Which version of business_time gem are you using?  It looks like it was fixed here: https://github.com/bokmann/business_time/issues/211

@BenTrewern  version of gem 'business_time', '~> 0.9.0'. Can you please suggest which version to upgrade for ruby version 3.1.0

I can't see any reason to not try the latest.  Anything >= 0.11.0 should work with Ruby 3.1.x.  Also why wouldn't you upgrade to Ruby 3.1.6?

@BenTrewern Thanks for response. It worked with 0.11.0. Also, will upgrade to 3.1.6.
